# Laravel Namespace, how does it work?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, composer-php

I am new to Laravel 5 and I would like someone to explain to me how exactly Laravel's namespacing works.

So I had a class named `Variant` in `app/models/Variant.php` my code looks like this

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Variant extends Model{
  /*Some code*/
}
```

in my `route.php` I have:

```
use App\Variant;
/*calls Variant::all() some where in code*/
```

Then I get an error saying `Variant` is not defined. However, if I change my namespace in `Variant.php` from `namespace App` to `namespace App\Models` and in `route.php` from `use App\Variant` to `use App\Models\Variant` everything magically works.

Why is that? Does it have to do with php namespace or the `classmap` property in composer.json? I am very confused.

Comment: If the file is `app/models/Variant.php` then the namespace will be `App\Models` and `use` will be `App\Models\Variant`. Why were you led to believe it should be `App` and  `App\Variant`?

Comment: See [PSR-4 autoloading standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) on how the autoloading works for laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes are probably loaded by composer. What's the content of it - `autoloading` section in particular?

I guess it's loaded by [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard, which respects director-name\file-name pattern.

Meaning:

- `App\Variant` is sought in `app/Variant.php`
- `App\Models\Variant` is sought in `app/models/Variant.php`

Therefore, when you change your namespace to the one corresponding with your directory path, it works.